# Character to binary function doesn't work as expected

Tags: c, binary

I have made a function to translate a number to its binary form:

```
size_t atobin (char n)
{
    size_t bin= 0, pow;
    for (size_t c= 1; n>0; c++)
    {
        pow= 1;
        for (size_t i= 1; i<c; i++) //This loop is for getting the power of 10
            pow*= 10;
        bin+= (n%2)*pow;
        n/= 2;
    }
    return bin;
}
```

It works great for numbers 1 to 127, but for greater numbers (128 to 255) the result is 0... I've tried using the type `long long unsigned int` for each variable but the result was the same. Someone has an idea about why?

Comment: `char` is signed, make it `unsigned char`

Comment: @IłyaBursov Strictly speaking, that's not true. `char` is either signed or unsigned, but `unsigned char` is guaranteed to be unsigned.

Comment: @user16217248 right, it is implementation defined, but on x86 is usually signed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char` by default in C is considered to be of signed.

`char` is of 8 bits(mostly). And for signed char the MSB is used for sign. As a result you can only use 7 bits.

(`0111 1111`)<sub>`2`</sub> = (`127`)<sub>`10`</sub> The maximum value that your fucntion can work with. (as you are passing a type of variable which can hold `127` at max).

If you use unsigned char then the MSB is not used as sign-bit. All 8 bits are used giving us a maximum possible value (`1111 1111`)<sub>`2`</sub> = (`255`)<sub>`10`</sub>

For signed number min/max value is `-127` to `+127`.

For unsigned number min/max value is `0` to `+255`.

So even if you make the type of the passed parameter `unsigned char` the maximum value it can hold is `+255`.

---

#### A bit more detail:

**Q)** What happens when you assign `>127` values to your `char` parameter?

It is signed char by default. It is of 8 bits. But it can't hold it. So what will happen?

The result is implementation defined. But

Suppose the value is `130`. In binary it is `10000010`. In most of the cases this returns `-126`. So that will be the value of `n`.
`n>0;` fails. Loop is never entered. And it returns `0`.

---

Now if we make it unsigned char then it can hold values between 0 and 255 (inclusive). And that is what you want to have here.

---

Note:

**Q)** What happens when `>255` values are stored in unsigned char?

> The value is reduced to modulo of `(max value unsigned char can hold+1)` which is
>   256.
>
> So apply modulo operation and put the result. That will be stored in
>   unsigned char.